# regex irregular format string input

Tags: regex

i have this format of string:

```
MY TITLE OF STRING 5 - EP.2
MY TITLE OF STRING 6 - EP.3
```

But in some cases this rule jump and my string can become that way:

```
MY TITLE OF STRING 5- EP.2
MY TITLE OF STRING 6-EP.3
```

This is a my regex

```
(\d*)\s-\s.*?EP.\s*(\d*)
```

but works only standard case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make the first `\s` match zero or more occurrences using `*` quantifier:

```
(\d+)\s*-\s*EP.\s*(\d+)
       ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v09vo0/1/)

If you need to match any 0+ chars as few as possible between the `-` and `EP`, re-insert `.*?` in the pattern

```
(\d+)\s*-\s*.*?EP.\s*(\d+)
```

Comment: @BillyD. Could you *accept* the answer if is solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun as Wiktor already gave a working answer, this one will also work :

`(\d+)[\s-]+EP\.(\d+)$`.

**Explanation**

`(\d+)` at least one digit

`[\s-]+` one or more hyphen or space

`EP\.` followed by EP.

`(\d+)$` at least one digit until end of string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YItnI3/1)